# AWS EMR Spark file splitting

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have an Apache Spark job run on AWS EMR service. It reads text file with domains from S3 bucket, and does some processing. Input file for 10K domains has size about 250Kb.

When I run job, only 2 tasks are created. And no matter what cluster size I use it doesn't run them in parallel.

Example of code to read input file:

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(appName).getOrCreate

val domains = sc.textFile("s3://bucket/file.txt")
```

I found that there is `fs.s3.block.size` option that controls file read splitting (and default value is bigger than my input file). But I couldn't find a place where to apply it. Tried the next configuration:

```
[
  {
    "classification": "emrfs-site", 
    "properties": {"fs.s3.block.size":"20480"}, 
    "configurations": []
  }
]
```

But it didn't have any effect.

What configuration can I use to increase Spark tasks for my input file?

AWS EMR release 5.29.0

Example of input file:

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
...
```

Comment: The example code looks bad. How did you load the "multiple files"? Have you just repeat that code?

Comment: I have only one input file. Plan is to periodically put input file to S3 bucket, and create AWS EMR cluster to process it.

Comment: It is better to give us the file contents example.

Comment: Just domains list - one per line.

domain1
domain2
domain3
...

Comment: Then, you can try with the parallel list. `.par` and `foreach`